# Sublime Text: prevent new line comment

Tags: comments, sublimetext2

I am not completely sure if this not a plugin, but after starting a line comment in .js file, for example, when I hit enter the next line starts with "//" as well.  This is kind of annoying. Is there a simple way to remove this?

Comment: It must be a plugin, because I don't see this behavior in ST2. What plugins do you have installed? If you use Package Control, go to `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings-User` and the full list will be there.

Comment: Excellent! I think I found it.  For DocBlockr it was the  {"jsdocs_extend_double_slash": true}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is indeed caused by the package DocBlockr.

When using this package, you can hit `shift + enter` to prevent the `//` from appearing on your new line.

Answer (score 15):

In "Preferences -> Package Settings -> Doc Blockr -> Settings Default" you can find lines:

// If true, then pressing enter while in a double-slash comment (like this one)
// will automatically add two slashes to the next line as well

> "jsdocs_extend_double_slash": true,

If you want to disable this behavior go to "Preferences -> Package Settings -> Doc Blockr -> Settings Default" and add

```
{
  "jsdocs_extend_double_slash": false
}
```

Comment: Better if you add it in user preference file. Thanks a lot for the info.